# Rails model through controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When creating a model function does it get seen to the controller?

I have a model present and i have the following function

```
before_create :check_exists
attr_accessible :customer_id, :event_id
#RELATIONSHIP
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :event

  private
    def check_exists
    present = Present.find_or_create_by_customer_id_and_event_id(:customer.id => current_customer.id, :event_id => self.event_id)
    end
```

How do I know that self.event_id is being use properly, how do i call this resource properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Yes, the method can be accessed through controllers.*

`:customer_id` and `:event_id` are supposed to be both properties of the model instance, so they will be used accordingly within your method. All you have to do is call `check_exists` from any `Present` instance (not the `Present` class, for this is not declared as static method).

Luck.